# How can you install the BizTalk application onto the BizTalk DR servers?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, disaster-recovery

How can you install the BizTalk application onto the BizTalk DR servers?

I can see how if we have the SQL log shipping to the DR SQL Server, we have DR at the database level ...

**But how does this work for the BizTalk application server level?**

So what about the installation of the BizTalk application onto the DR BizTalk server, so the assemblies are in the GAC, when the DR database isn't available because of the log shipping?

And ditto any IIS web directories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, you just do. Perhaps you're overthinking this.

You install the applications on the DR servers just as you would the 'main' servers.  In fact, if you talking about Log Shipping DR, they are part of the same Group so you must deploy to DR same time, same process you use to on main servers.

Basically, there's no difference application wise.

Comment: Still getting my head around DR, so next stupid questions. Part of same group ... would/should the DR group show the same server as PROD?  Our DR group shows the SQL on the DR SQL. Plus I can't open the Admin Console because my domain id can't login to BizTalkMgmtDb ... presume because I've just started here. So how could install an application on the DR boxes?

Comment: If you're talking about the Log Shipping DR feature of BizTalk, then yes, all the servers, Primary and Backup sites, are part of the same group, joined to the same database and all.  They why the Log Shipping, to keep a copy of the databases at the backup site.

Comment: So if the BizTalk DR group shows a different SQL Server, than the LIVE group, it sounds like there isn't DR for BizTalk

Comment: No, it's DR.  Have you read through the setup guide?  It explains all of this.  The SQL Alias is either redirected or changed when moving from site to site.